# HP Smart Array Controller Not Showing in BIOS

Tags: windows-server-2016, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I am currently setting up a HP DL380p Gen8 and I am trying to use a Smart Array P822 controller with it.

However, this controller is not showing up in the BIOS so it doesn't detect in windows. The server has a built-in P420i that does show up and is working out of the box.

Is there a change that needs to be made for this card to be recognized?

If anyone with any past experience of this could help I would be very grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a faulty card.

We had a spare which when I tried it worked first time with no changes having to be made.